# Detect Beacons when app closed with Titanium for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, titanium, android-ibeacon

I'm trying to listen Beacons when the app is closed in Android (not in background).

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium with SDK version 5.2.2GA and for the Beacons I'm using the module com.liferay.beacons. 
Someone know the way to do this, if this is posible or if there is another module to do this.

I'm testing in marshmallow and kitkat. in both works fine when the app is open or in background.

Comment: Same here, did you find something? I've been trying to create an Application subclass to startMonitoring but have no idea on how to do this in a module =\